# MATLAB issue with Exception Handling

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I am trying to handle exceptions gracefully such that when a user enters a character, when a number is expected, he is notified with a custom warning/message.

I know that the try, catch has the following syntax:

```
try
   statements
catch exception
   statements
end
```

I have been trying something like this, to no avail:

```
number = input('Enter number'); 
try
    assert(isnumeric(number));
catch ME
    warning('NOT A NUMBER');
end
```

I do not understand why the above code fails since `assert` if it is false, displays the error message 'Assertion Failed'.

I know that using `try` and `catch` is a bit of a sledgehammer approach, but I would like to understand how to implement the above functionality. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help command:

> input  Prompt for user input.
>
> RESULT = input(PROMPT) displays the PROMPT string on the screen, waits
>       for input from the keyboard, **evaluates any expressions in the input**,
>       and returns the value in RESULT. To evaluate expressions, input accesses
>       variables in the current workspace. If you press the return key without
>       entering anything, input returns an empty matrix.

Therefore if a user types in "goat" MATLAB will try to evaluate the variable named "goat". That is not helpful for this problem.

However looking further down the help command:

> STR = input(PROMPT,'s') returns the entered text as a MATLAB string,
>       **without evaluating expressions**.

This is what is more applicable to your problem.

```
number = input('Enter number', 's');
try
    assert(~isnan(str2double(number)));
catch ME
    warning('NOT A NUMBER');
end
```